# SSL cache in Windows or Outlook - Is this on topic here or better for Sec.SE?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/40179/396) on Sec.SE and can rework it to fit on this site if you think the issue is on topic.

There is the security aspect of the question which is good to know where and how windows works, and there is the operations part that applies to changing the OL certificate.

Should I migrate or ask a new question here?

Comment: I'd say leave it there unless they show it no love. FWIW, IE and Outlook use schannel for everything SSL related. Dunno on the rest of the question.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem to be overtly off topic on either site. As ChrisS says if it gets no love in a few days you can always flag and ask for it to be migrated here.